# Smarty fetch vs smarty display

Tags: php, smarty

I have to display a small template inside a main template such that the small template is displayed based on the ajax reposne.I have gotten to the stage where I am getting the parameter after an ajax request.

```
$smarty=new Smarty(); 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    &&$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')
{
    // echo  "<pre>";
     //print_r("Yes");
     //echo "</pre>";
     echo $smarty->fetch('../templates/small-page.tpl');
} else {
     $smarty->display('../templates/index-page.tpl'); 
}
```

Here the echo statement is not working .When I uncomment the print_r function I can see in firebug that the html contains "Yes" but it's not displayed on the page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the code on the client side ? Are you using the result of the ajax call to display it on the page ? it seems like you are doing a get without exploiting the result. The smarty code seems correct.

Comment: @jerome This the js code.I am unsure as to how to display a smart template as responsexml on the client side.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //Not sure how to diplay a smarty template as a result of responseText or responseXMl
          
            
        }
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output of your smarty template is in XML format, you can use the responseXML property of xmlhttp, but only if php outputs the correct mime-type.

try :

```
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo $smarty->fetch('../templates/small-page.tpl');
```

and then on the client side,

```
alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
```

Tell me if it works !

Comment: @Jerome.Awesome Thanks you , I appreciate your help.Finally do we have to set the mime-type whenever we send a request or response?

Comment: Usually you do not have to bother with mime-types. In your specific case, the browser will not try to fill responseXML if the mime-type is not set. Can you 'accept' the answer if it works for you now ? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Smarty is involved in your problem. Smarty outputs whatever comes out of the processing of its compiled template.

Imagine "Yes" comes out.

On the client side, you have

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { 
        //Not sure how to diplay a smarty template as a result of responseText or responseXMl 
     } 
}
```

responseText will hold "Yes". so for example, try:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { 
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
     } 
}
```

If this works, you will have to decide what you want to do with the text.

Comment: I have tried an alert(xmlhttp.responseText), i am returning an xml output  , so I can see the xml being returned but inside html page.eg like  I have the complete xml inside  <html><book></book></html>,with this i cannot traverse using dom elements and as it gives me the message that responseXML is null. If i pass it as html then again I get the complete page .Any direction to go from here?